# Is $or part of Mongo in a Meteor App?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am assuming this is a mongo syntax thing.  It's from a meteor app:

```
const { selectedSectionId } = this.state;

                const assignmentsSelector = {
                    formativeId: this.props.formative._id,
                    $or: [{ public: true }],
                 };

                 if (selectedSectionId && selectedSectionId !== 'all') {
                    assignmentsSelector.$or.push({ sectionId: selectedSectionId });
                 }
```

In the above what's the `$or`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As defined in the MongoDB documentation:

> The $or operator performs a logical OR operation on an array of two or more 
>   expressions and selects the documents that satisfy at least one of the expressions.

It appears that your *$or* array within *assignmentsSelector* only contains an expression to see if any document has a *public* property that is true. The conditional underneath the definition of *assignmentsSelector* provides the opportunity for you to add another expression to that array so that the *$or* operator will kick in.

For more on how *$or* behaves, visit the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/).